# What is the best way to thank a moderator?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently posted an answer to a new question.  Shortly thereafter, a moderator deleted my answer and left a helpful comment correctly pointing out that I misinterpreted the question.  I wanted to thank the moderator (rumtscho), but there was no way to post further comments on a deleted answer, even if it is your own (which is kinda too bad).

What is the best way to thank a moderator?

*P.S. Thanks rumtscho!  I did, indeed, initially misunderstand that question!*

Answer (score 1):

This kind of interaction on a personal/social level would best happen in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan). (Provided you have the required reputation - and you do, just mentioning it for other users.)

Our mod team is usually pingable, if not some other mod will happily use their super-ping ability to ensure the message reaches the addressee.

In a pinch, I admit I have used the comment function elsewhere to ping a specific user, and while that’s technically an abuse of the comment function, we mods will look the other way if it happens rarely and the comments get deleted again after a short while.